# material design and minSdkVersion=10

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, android-min-sdk

I am developing an application for Android, using the style of design materials and therefore the `minSdkVersion = 22`.

What happens is that I want the application support from the `minSdkVersion = 10`.

It could make various styles one for each `minSdkVersion`.

What think?

Comment: take a look http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Design Support Library brings a number of important material design components to all developers and to all **Android 2.1 or higher devices**.
Here's a very good tutorial to begin with:
http://hmkcode.com/material-design-app-android-design-support-library-appcompat/
Add this to your `build.gradle` file to get support.
 compile

> 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'